# openvpn fails when started as service

Tags: 16.04, vpn, services, openvpn

### Setup

OpenVPN is acting as a **client** on a Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS machine.
The openvpn config is stored in `/etc/openvpn/myclient.conf`.
All additional data, e.g. keys are stored in the conf file as well.

```
# openvpn --version

**`OpenVPN 2.3.10`**` x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jan  9 2019
library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
```

### The Problem

When trying to start openvpn as a service, the **startup fails**:

```
 # systemctl start openvpn@myclient.service
    Job for openvpn@myclient.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status openvpn@myclient.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.



# systemctl status openvpn@myclient.service
● openvpn@myclient.service - OpenVPN connection to myclient
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since So 2019-08-04 13:03:33 CEST; 1min 44s ago
     Docs: man:openvpn(8)
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn23ManPage
           https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
  Process: 16134 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-%i --status /run/openvpn/%i.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --script-security 2 --config /etc/openvpn/%i.conf --writepid /run/openvpn/%i.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 04 13:03:33 hostname systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN connection to myclient...
Aug 04 13:03:33 hostname systemd[1]: openvpn@myclient.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 04 13:03:33 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to myclient.
Aug 04 13:03:33 hostname systemd[1]: openvpn@myclient.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 04 13:03:33 hostname systemd[1]: openvpn@myclient.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

journalctl shows **openvpn cannot open the config file**:

```
# journalctl -xe

-- Unit openvpn@myclient.service has begun starting up.`**`
Aug 04 13:10:03 hostname ovpn-myclient[17349]: Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: /etc/openvpn/myclient.conf`**`
Aug 04 13:10:03 hostname ovpn-myclient[17349]: Use --help for more information.
Aug 04 13:10:03 hostname systemd[1]: openvpn@myclient.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 04 13:10:03 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenVPN connection to myclient.

[...]

Aug 04 13:10:03 hostname systemd[1]: openvpn@myclient.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 04 13:10:03 hostname systemd[1]: openvpn@myclient.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

However, **starting openvpn manually** via `# openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/myclient.conf` **works as expected**.

### What I've tried

- Changing the config files **permissions** (from 644 to 755; the file is owned root:root)
- Checking **AppArmor** (there is no profile for openvpn, and disabling apparmor completely didn't help either)
- Renaming the config file and try again